# Problem getting the output of an Azure Function in a Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I'm having some problems when trying to get the output of an Azure Function in my Logic app.

When I look at the azure function output, in the body, the `"m_StringValue"` returns what I want. When I put a condition just after that to check if the azure function body returned what I want, it returns false.

**Azure Logic App flow:**

[image: Azure Logic App flow]

**Azure Logic App output:**

[image: Azure Logic App output]

The app code is the following

```
{
    "$connections": {
        "value": {
            "azureblob_1": {
                "connectionId": "x",
                "connectionName": "azureblob-5",
                "id": "x"
            },
            "office365": {
                "connectionId": "x",
                "connectionName": "office365-5",
                "id": "x"
            }
        }
    },
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Is_from_a_known_sender": {
                "actions": {
                    "Should_be_forwarded_to_a": {
                        "actions": {},
                        "else": {
                            "actions": {
                                "Should_be_forwarded_to_b": {
                                    "actions": {
                                        "For_each": {
                                            "actions": {
                                                "Condition_2": {
                                                    "actions": {},
                                                    "expression": {
                                                        "and": [
                                                            {
                                                                "contains": [
                                                                    "@body('Parse_JSON')?['properties']?['m_StringValue']",
                                                                    "abc"
                                                                ]
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    "runAfter": {
                                                        "Parse_JSON": [
                                                            "Succeeded"
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    "type": "If"
                                                },
                                                "Create_blob_for_each_attachment": {
                                                    "inputs": {
                                                        "body": "@base64ToBinary(items('For_each')?['ContentBytes'])",
                                                        "host": {
                                                            "connection": {
                                                                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob_1']['connectionId']"
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                        "method": "post",
                                                        "path": "/datasets/default/files",
                                                        "queries": {
                                                            "folderPath": "/attachments",
                                                            "name": "@items('For_each')?['Name']",
                                                            "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "runAfter": {},
                                                    "runtimeConfiguration": {
                                                        "contentTransfer": {
                                                            "transferMode": "Chunked"
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "type": "ApiConnection"
                                                },
                                                "ExtractTextFromPDF": {
                                                    "inputs": {
                                                        "body": "@body('Get_blob_content')",
                                                        "function": {
                                                            "id": "x"
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "runAfter": {
                                                        "Get_blob_content": [
                                                            "Succeeded"
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    "type": "Function"
                                                },
                                                "Get_blob_content": {
                                                    "inputs": {
                                                        "host": {
                                                            "connection": {
                                                                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob_1']['connectionId']"
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                        "method": "get",
                                                        "path": "/datasets/default/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(body('Create_blob_for_each_attachment')?['Id']))}/content",
                                                        "queries": {
                                                            "inferContentType": true
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "runAfter": {
                                                        "Create_blob_for_each_attachment": [
                                                            "Succeeded"
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    "type": "ApiConnection"
                                                },
                                                "Parse_JSON": {
                                                    "inputs": {
                                                        "content": "@body('ExtractTextFromPDF')",
                                                        "schema": {
                                                            "properties": {
                                                                "m_MaxCapacity": {
                                                                    "type": "integer"
                                                                },
                                                                "m_StringValue": {
                                                                    "type": "string"
                                                                }
                                                            },
                                                            "type": "object"
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "runAfter": {
                                                        "ExtractTextFromPDF": [
                                                            "Succeeded"
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    "type": "ParseJson"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "foreach": "@triggerBody()?['Attachments']",
                                            "runAfter": {},
                                            "type": "Foreach"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "expression": {
                                        "and": [
                                            {
                                                "contains": [
                                                    "@triggerBody()?['From']",
                                                    "xandreu"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "runAfter": {},
                                    "type": "If"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "contains": [
                                        "@triggerBody()?['From']",
                                        "test"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "If"
                    }
                },
                "expression": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "or": [
                                {
                                    "contains": [
                                        "@triggerBody()?['From']",
                                        "xandreu"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "equals": [
                                "@triggerBody()?['HasAttachment']",
                                true
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "If"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_new_email_arrives": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/Mail/OnNewEmail",
                    "queries": {
                        "fetchOnlyWithAttachment": true,
                        "folderPath": "Inbox",
                        "importance": "Any",
                        "includeAttachments": true
                    }
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()?['value']",
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your Azure Function Code?

Comment: Could you also, please, share the code from View Code from Logic App? It is possible that sometimes parameter in condition is referring to wrong action output and we cannot see it on screen

Comment: edited the post with the code @ThiagoCustodio

Comment: edited the post with the code @IvanIgnatiev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition Body contains "abc" is wrong. It think it is reading Body as an object.

Try adding a "Parse Json" statement and then change your condition to only check the string value field.

[image]

Comment: Tried it and got this [error](https://i.imgur.com/8ddAL0h.png)

Comment: I agree that transformation of the output of function to object is the correct approach, but in my case condition `contains` works even if it is not transformed. I think there is an issue with references @XaviAndreu, please, share the Logic App code

Comment: You're json appears to be incorrect. There are 3 layers of properties. Can you post a screenshot of the "Parse Json" task, but expanded to show the schema?

Comment: I don't know why it was triplicated but [here](https://i.imgur.com/mCvoEtI.png)'s a screenshot of the parse json now after redoing it and the error persists